# To display the name of the department that has the least student count in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

**Tables:**

```
Department (dept_id,dept_name)
Students(student_id,student_name,dept_id)
```

I am using Oracle. I have to print the name of that department that has the minimum no. of students. Since I am new to SQL, I am stuck on this problem. So far, I have done this:

```
select d.department_id,d.department_name,
from Department d
join Student s on s.department_id=d.department_id
where rownum between 1 and 3
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
order by count(s.student_id) asc;
```

The output is incorrect. It is coming as `IT,SE,CSE` whereas the output should be `IT,CSE,SE`! Is my query right? Or is there something missing in my query?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oracle and MySQL belong to the same company, but are different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: MySQL. Sorry, my bad. Will remove Oracle tag

Comment: Is rownum a field in any of the 2 tables?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I used it because Limit 3 (edited) wouldn't work!

Comment: There is no rownum in mysql  : use limit 3

Comment: Then you are going to get a syntax error in MySQL, since MySQL does not support rownum. However, Oracle does. So, perhaps your question is for Oracle after all, since you claimed in the question that you got a result.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am very very new at this. But still it doesn't come...

Comment: What does not come? Pls be specific and pls also be specific on what product you use. You question is absolutely not clear on that.

Comment: I have updated the question and have tried to provide all the details. "But it still doesn't come" meant that the output expected is not matching the output I am getting (as stated in the question). I am asking if the query I have written is right or not. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you limit your join to three rows? That makes your result completely arbitrary.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? (Use `SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE` to find out.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities:

```
select dept_id, dept_name 
  from (
    select dept_id, dept_name, 
           rank() over (order by cnt nulls first) rn
      from department
      left join (select dept_id, count(1) cnt 
                   from students 
                   group by dept_id) using (dept_id) )
  where rn = 1
```

Group data from table `students` at first, join table `department`, rank numbers, take first row(s).

`left join` are used is used to guarantee that we will check departments without students.
`rank()` is used in case that there are two or more departments with minimal number of students.

Answer (score 0):

To find the department(s) with the minimum number of students, you'll have to count per department ID and then take the ID(s) with the minimum count.

As of Oracle 12c this is simply:

```
select department_id
from student
group by department_id
order by count(*)
fetch first row with ties
```

You then select the departments with an ID in the found set.

```
select * from department where id in (<above query>);
```

In older versions you could use `RANK` instead to rank the departments by count:

```
select department_id, rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
from student
group by department_id
```

The rows with `rnk = 1` would be the department IDs with the lowest count. So you could select the departments with:

```
select * from department where (id, 1) in (<above query>);
```